# How to convert javascript variable to C# string in Razor View MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have a model and it has one property as `Dictionary<string, bool>`. There are multiple links and I am calling same javascript method on click  and passing link id. Model dictionary key will be link id. so I want to set dictionary value true of false based on some condition using this key. I tried a lot but not able to do, Please help me out.
I want to do something like this.

```
function LinkClick(id){
    string strKey = id; //strKey is C# string
    @Model.DictionaryIdSet[strKey] = true;
}
```

Comment: Why are you mixing razor and JavaScript? You really need to pick one. If you go JS, you'll use an AJAX remoting call to your MVC Api Controller.

Comment: Razor runs at server, the only way to archive this is by posting this value to the server.

Comment: "I want to set dictionary value true of false based on some condition using this key"  The dictionary is part of the server side code.  The only way to affect it is to post the value to the server (using AJAX for example).  You are getting confused between how server-side and client-side work.

Comment: Keep in mind that your Razor views are executed on the server side, after that they generate HTML and sent to client browser. And is the client browser that execute the JS. So, bassicly it is not bossible to achieve want you want. The only way is to so as @Teagan42.

If you can provider more context about your final goal with that dictionary, it will be more easy to give you some advise.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot work with C# object in js code (on client side), but what you can do is

1. GET your dictionary as json - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3646514/5100673)
2. then POST it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1999617/5100673)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  @{
           Model.DictionaryIdSet[strKey] = true;
  }
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. I also recommend you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.

Comment: It's not a guess , i used above code in my project and it worked well.

Comment: Then please edit the answer to explain that. An answer that just says "Try this" with code doesn't really explain much.