# Nested binding in ASP.NET MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, data-binding

**Description**

A nested object needs to be bound to a dropdown, there already is a preselected value for the nested objects. The possible values are of an enum type. The dropdownlist with some other data will be posted back to the controller.

Code - types & classes:

```
[Serializable]
public enum DummyEnum
{
   DummyZero = 0,
   DummyOne = 1
}

public class Dummy
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<Guid, DummyEnum> DummyEnum { get; set; }
}

public class DummyViewModel
{
    public Dictionary<Guid, List<Dummy>> Dummies { get; set; }
}

public class DummyController
{
    private void Init(DummyViewModel model)
    {
       model.EnumList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DummyEnum))
                    .Cast<DummyEnum>()
                    .Select(e => new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = (e).ToString(),
                        Text = e.ToString()
                    });
    }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<td>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
         m => m.Dummies[dummiesKey][dummyIndex]
                 .Enum[Id],
         new SelectList(Model.EnumList, "Value", "Text", e.ToString()))
</td>

<select 
    data-val="true" 
    data-val-required="The Enum field is required." 
    id="Dummies_guid__0__Enum_guid_" 
    name="Dummies[guid][0].Enum[guid]" 
    style="display: none;"
>
    <option value="DummyOne">DummyOne</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="DummyZero ">DummyZero</option>
</select>
```

### Problem

The problem is that the model doesn't seem to be able to map the payload back to an object or misses the reference to the bound object. Everything is filled in correctly the guid, index and the value of the enum.

Payload:

```
Dummies[guid][0].Enum[guid]: DummyZero     
Dummies[guid][0].Enum[guid]: DummyZero
```

**Attempts**

I tried with the following ideas but they weren't successfull for me.

- [model not binding to dictionary](https://coderedirect.com/questions/387165/mvc-model-not-binding-to-dictionary)
- [binding dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929162/bind-to-a-dictionary-of-lists-of-lists-of-bools-with-a-strongly-typed-mvc-view-b)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem as stated in the question had to do with mvc converting `Dictionary` to a List<KeyValuePair<Guid, List>>binding or use `JSON`.

All that needs to be done is break down the object as mvc would and provide the necessary data. As explained in [dicitionary binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248739/mvc-model-not-binding-to-dictionary).

The object was of type `Dictionary<Guid, List<Dummy>>`. So the object actually becomes `List<KeyValuePair<Guid, List<List<KeyValuePair<Guid, enum>>>>>`.

### Now to break it down

MVC needs the index of the first object that is being used. To get this index we need to covert the dictionary to a list ourself. More specific the values or keys of the dictionarys.

```
var dummies= Model.Dummies[key];
var dummiesIndex = Model.Dummies.Values.ToList().IndexOf(dummies);
```

The index needs to be provided along side the post. This can be done by adding it above the dropdown as a hidden field along side the key from the dictionary.

```
@Html.Hidden("dummies.Index", dummiesIndex)
@Html.Hidden("dummies[" + dummiesIndex + "].Key", key)
```

Next is the List of objects. Again the index needs to be provided for the binding.

```
 @Html.Hidden("dummies[" + dummiesIndex + "].Value.Index", dummyIndex)
```

The last step is another dictionary, this is just like the first dictionary

```
@Html.Hidden("dummies[" + dummiesIndex + "].DummyEnum.Index", dummyEnumIndex)
@Html.Hidden("dummies[" + dummiesIndex + "].DummyEnum.Key", yourKey)
```

For the value you want to actually post you need to follow the complete path like above.

```
@Html.DefaultCombo("dummies[" + dummiesIndex + "].DummyEnum[" + dummyEnumIndex+ "]", "Value", "Text", Model.EnumList, enum)
```

Now MVC can remap your objects.

Answer (score 0):

The front-end response will be in that form that you'll set it there. Then the ASP middleware will parse all those strings back to an object at your back-end.

So key moments here are:

- a controller action parameter type - it could be any of your types but it should correlate with your front-end;
- front-end's `select` element `name` attribute value - it should contain full existing path.

As I got from your code example the following.

1. You have `DummyViewModel` view model class. It has property `Dummies`.
2. You have `Dummy` class, that nested in `DummyViewModel` as `Dummies`. 2nd level dictionary.
3. You have `DummyEnum` enum class, that is in use at `DummyEnum` values. Same names, different adjacent levels.
4. The SelectList values are OK. They are directly from the enum.
5. Based on the structure, to set up a first enum value you need to navigate its level by setting KEY and VALUE. Then do it again for another level. For me, the first enum value in this structure should have something like this:

```
Dummies[dummiesKeyGuid][dummyIndexId].DummyEnum[dummyEnumKeyGuid];
```

Where you have the following types in each step:

- `Dummies[dummiesKeyGuid]` is `<List<Dummy>>`;
- `Dummies[dummiesKeyGuid][dummyIndexId]` is `<Dummy>`;
- `Dummies[dummiesKeyGuid][dummyIndexId].DummyEnum[dummyEnumKeyGuid]` is `<DummyEnum>`.

So `@Html.DropDownListFor(...)` should be updated to set the path as `name`.

Also:

1. your action should take the `Dummies` type as a parameter.

```
ActionResult SomeFromProcessingAction(DummyViewModel Dummies)
```

2. you should handle the passed stringified parameters map to the `Dictionary` type. It could be used outside of ASP (front-end) but has the issue. Please, check this post and its topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29820891/6344916. Sometimes, it is easier to not use the `Dictionary` there. Just other classes like List or Array.

From your HTML example, I didn't get the `m.Dummies` type to have in its structure the `Enum` field. `dummiesKey` can't have `"guid"` value. GUID is another type that can be made `ToString()` easily but not otherwise.

IMHO. Too many `Dummy`s in the names. It confuses and breaks its understanding.

Also, its nested structure is VERY cumbersome. You could use smaller user forms to set the values and take smaller objects or event values on your back-end instead of the huge object parameters.

The List class has no mapping requirements, just denormalize your dictionaries and it will be easier to map them. The same with their navigation on the front-end. If required, you can make the List `ToDictionary()`. :)=)

For example, `Dummy` could be written using `List<T>`:

```
public class SomeElement
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public DummyEnum Enum { get; set; }
}

public class Dummy //kind of aggregation
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public List <SomeElement> DummyEnum { get; set; }
}
```

And so on with `DummyViewModel`. Or get rid of it and use some List  directly.

Hope, this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is not related to nested properties or input naming and your implementation seems fine.

The issue you encountered is linked to `Dictionary<Guid, ...>` default model binder behavior. The default binder simply does not seem to handle it correctly. (ie. Dictionaries with `Guid` as keys)

I have reproduced your issue and then switched to `Dictionary<string, ...>` and everything worked fine this time.

The only way your could overcome this should probably be to implement your own model binder for `Dictionary<Guid, object>`.

I tried to understand the root problem and it seems to be located [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/a68a57535d0adeda2b1846764e5eafd02fdeb12d/src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs#L858) (Invalid explicit cast from string to Guid) as also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23374611/4627054) (found later :-)...)